# Setting up Completion in Emacs' python mode

Tags: python, emacs, ide, code-completion, python-mode

After having seen this bug fix http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18582

I wonder how I setup Emacs to provide completion of imports in python-mode.

Further are there other completions possible in Emacs' builtin python.el?

Comment: You could look at auto-complete.el

Comment: Here is the link to the python-mode dictionary -- you can see if there is anything in there that interests you -- moreover, it looks simple enough to add your own additional definitions:  https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/dict/python-mode  If you encounter a bug, then deal with it -- i.e., try to fix it yourself, and if you can't, then seek help and/or submit a bug report.  Don't be shy -- dig in -- get your hands dirty -- yada yada yada . . .! :)